# How should jar without resourses work? (maven-shade-plugin with excluded resources)

Tags: java, maven, microservices

I have a legacy code (which suppose to be 100% working) without any documentation. This code consists of several separate services which do some tasks (like working with RabbitMQ, inserting some records into Postgres DB, and so on).
Each and every service in its pom.xml in maven-shade-plugin configuration has resourses folder being excluded from the resulting jar. Like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-shade-plugin-version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>log4j2.xml</exclude>
                            <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
                            <exclude>update.sql</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As a result, when I try to run any of such jars (`with java -jar any_of_my_jars.jar`) - they fail, cuz they need application.properties and all other resources to run.

So the question is: it should be I'm missing something. I either should run them in some other way, or I should deploy them somewhere. Can someone plz explain to me how such jars can be used to be working jars?

Comment: Just a wild guess: These config files are excluded from the JAR since they are supposed to reside outside the JAR to be able to change them on the runtime system any time.

Comment: @GeroldBroser you mean this is just a design of configuration the whole app, and nothing about something like a requirements of any tool/framework (assuming only public, well known tools/frameworks)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. See, for instance, the file (of my Eclipse installation) `/home/<username>/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.19.0_1944432518_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` which is in fact a `key=value` properties file that resides outside of any Eclipse plugin JAR. And I know from the past that there are some other (even many?) tools/frameworks that use such for their configs. I did that myself in some of my applications.